Chanting of Gayatri mantra without initiation
As a common householder , can I chant the Gayatri mantra daily ? Will it have any bad consequences ?( note that I am not initiated by any sampradaya )
My Gayatri mantra chanting is like - aum Bhur Bhuvah swaha tat savitur varenyam,bhargo devasya dhimahi dhiyoyonah prachodayat, aum.
Is this a correct way to get any result from the mantra chanting?

In the Kularnav Tantra it is said




Does it mention that Gayatri mantra specifically does not bear any fruit without initiation ? Please donot give answers which creates confusion .

@Sillyasker it would rather harm you if it is not taken from guru but from somewhere else but everyone can do mahamantra(hare krishna)/naam jap without initiation

@Sillyasker Gayatri Mantra is a "mantra" so yes it does mention it

my father used to recite the meter. I would listen to him. Does that mean I can also?

@blue_eggo no you cannot it must be taken from a bona fide guru who follows all the rules

@blue_eggo you can only chant Gayatri Mantra only if your mantra diksha is done by a bona fide guru who follows all rules because in kularnav tantra it is said that if you chant mantra which is heard from somewhere else (other than guru) then it will only lead to disaster
